# Snail/spiral matrix PYTHON the program doesn't execute

Tags: python, matrix

first at all I want to thank you for your help. I'm trying to do a snail/spiral Matrix in python 3.6 like this

```
    [10 9  8  7]
    [11 16 15 6]
    [12 13 14 5]
    [1  2  3  4]
```

I've tried with this code for pair square matrices

```
    import numpy as np
    n=4
    M = np.zeros([n,n])
    init = 0
    nlimit = n-1
    c = 0         
    if (n%2==0):

        while (c<=(n*n)):

            for i in range(init,nlimit,1):
                c=c+1
                M[nlimit,i] = c

            for i in range(nlimit-1,init,-1):
                c=c+1
                M[i,nlimit] = c

            for i in range(nlimit-1,init,-1):
                c=c+1
                M[init,i] = c

            for i in range(init,nlimit-1,1):
                c=c+1
                M[i,init] = c

           init = init + 1
           nlimit = nlimit - 1

    print(M)
```

But when I run the program it remains loading for a long time and never does something, it doesn't show me mistakes, but it do nothing.

I don't know what is my mistake, please help me.

Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You get into an infinite loop when your counter `c` is equal to `n*n`. All the ranges in your `for` loops become empty, and `c = c + 1` is never executed anymore.

You need to change the check to `c < (n*n)` and the ranges:

```
import numpy as np
n = 4
M = np.zeros([n, n])
init = 0
nlimit = n - 1
c = 0
if (n % 2 == 0):
    while (c < (n*n)):
        for i in range(init, nlimit, 1):
            c = c + 1
            M[nlimit, i] = c
        for i in range(nlimit, init, -1):
            c = c + 1
            M[i, nlimit] = c
        for i in range(nlimit, init, -1):
            c = c + 1
            M[init, i] = c
        for i in range(init, nlimit, 1):
            c = c + 1
            M[i, init] = c
        init = init + 1
        nlimit = nlimit - 1

print(M)
```

It outputs:

```
[[ 10.   9.   8.   7.]
 [ 11.  16.  15.   6.]
 [ 12.  13.  14.   5.]
 [  1.   2.   3.   4.]]
```

As a bonus, you don't need to change much for odd numbers. For `n=5`, it outputs :

```
[[ 13.  12.  11.  10.   9.]
 [ 14.  23.  22.  21.   8.]
 [ 15.  24.   0.  20.   7.]
 [ 16.  17.  18.  19.   6.]
 [  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.]]
```

You only need to change the `while c` and add the last number in the center:

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
M = np.zeros([n, n])
init = 0
nlimit = n - 1
c = 0
while c < (n * n) - 1:
    for i in range(init, nlimit, 1):
        c = c + 1
        M[nlimit, i] = c
    for i in range(nlimit, init, -1):
        c = c + 1
        M[i, nlimit] = c
    for i in range(nlimit, init, -1):
        c = c + 1
        M[init, i] = c
    for i in range(init, nlimit, 1):
        c = c + 1
        M[i, init] = c
    init = init + 1
    nlimit = nlimit - 1

M[(n - 1) // 2, (n - 1) // 2] = n * n

print(M)
```

It now outputs:

```
[[ 13.  12.  11.  10.   9.]
 [ 14.  23.  22.  21.   8.]
 [ 15.  24.  25.  20.   7.]
 [ 16.  17.  18.  19.   6.]
 [  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.]]
```